# Deploy module works fine, but deploy individual menu item gives error

Tags: sharepoint, axapta, enterprise-portal

While deploying menu Item I receive an error:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Setup encountered an error during deployment of the Role Center and Enterprise Portal framework.

But deploying whole module works fine.

Also importing page gives an error as well as follows:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
>   Parameter name: startIndex

I've full control permission on sharepoint on that particular URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check your event log. I found that I was getting an error regarding write permissions to the root site.
"You need write permission to the root web site at ...."
Check to see what account is on the app pool in IIS Manager. You can open the site using that account and add your account